force writing right away to file with rsyslog
my ruby/rake daemon script logs to STDOUT. But thanks to systemd, logs are available to rsyslog.
systemd service:
[Unit]
Description=ruby rake daemon

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/rake/....
Type=simple
User=rake
Group=rake
ExecStart=/home/rake/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rake ....
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=rake

ryslog conf /etc/rsyslog.d/rake.conf
:programname, isequal, "rake" /var/log/rake.log
& stop

It actually works but it buffers the data so log file is not updated right away when I tail it but it waits for a chunk of data (a few lines, it looks to me).
How do I disable buffering?

By default, rsyslog will sync after every write, see here for how the prefix "-" to the filename will cause buffering. Have you tried running your program with output to a file, then tailing the file to see if it buffers?

you are right: it was a ruby Logger thing to buffer. rsyslog had nothing to do with that
